# multi Image: scroll as well as resize

Tags: iphone

I have 5 images. I want to display each image on a page (paging).
And per page can resize the image on that page (other pages still not changes).
How can i do it?

THank you.

Answer (score 0):

check the two examples for **ScrollViews** from Apple. They should help...

The more basic one (about **paging** etc.)
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

The advanced one (including **zooming**, etc.)
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html